# get : permission denied in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I execute the get command it says permission denied,
I tried the already given solution but didn't worked. Following is the command and its op

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ hadoop fs -get /user/hduser/Input/pg*.txt /home/vilas/Desktop/
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

get: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the permissions of this `/user/hduser` directory, maybe **hduser** does not have permission to access it, if so then you can execute the following command (as **hdfs** user)

```
hdfs dfs chown hduser:hduser /user/hduser
```

More information about chown [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#chown).

then try again.

Comment: after changing the owner and firing ll command .. I got following result..  but still its showing that permision denied  :                                             drwxr-xr-x 15 hduser hadoop 4096 Oct 12 05:16 hadoop

Comment: It seems the file is owned by hadoop, you need to change that file owner as well (using `hdfs` user) to `hduser`. Or you can change your user to `hadoop` and try again. The point is the file owner in HDFS and your system must have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

you must go into the desktop directory, open the terminal there and run the command

`hadoop fs -get /user/hduser/Input/pg*.txt .`